# WebSSO Spring + Angular redirect-uri

Tags: angular, spring, spring-security, oauth, single-sign-on

There is spring-web (security app).

Here is configuration:

```
   security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          *auth:
            provider: *auth
            client-name: Login with the Identity Server
            client-id: ${app.auth-client.client-id}
            client-secret: ${app.auth-client.client-secret}
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: ?????
    provider:
      *auth:
        token-uri: ${app.auth-client.server-url}/${app.auth-client.realm}/${app.auth-client.server-url-postfix}/token
        authorization-uri: ${app.auth-client.server-url}/${app.auth-client.realm}/${app.auth-client.server-url-postfix}/auth
        user-info-uri: ${app.auth-client.server-url}/${app.auth-client.realm}/${app.auth-client.server-url-postfix}/userinfo
        jwk-set-uri: ${app.auth-client.server-url}/${app.auth-client.realm}/${app.auth-client.server-url-postfix}/certs
```

The main quiestion is how to resolve redirect uri for UI?
There are 2 applications: back(spring) and front(angular)

It works with redirect-uri: `{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}`

But it works only with REST-API and back-end application.

In fact, I want to open UI page - if user isn't auntificated - redirect to auth-server using back.
After login - redirect back (redirect-ui ???) to UI page with credentials.

Classical way. But it doesn't wotk with separate UI. For tests I use keycloak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is trick:

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
              ...
                .oauth2Login()
                .successHandler((request, response, authentication) -> response.sendRedirect(clientProperties.getRedirectUriSuccess()))
```

Need to define redirect-uri to UI after success auth. It isn't the same redirect-uri from sso configuration.